# jquery .top is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm getting error from using top property in my jquery code. The code is about navigation dots on my slider. This is the link to my page: http://54.169.61.153/teavana
Below is my code. I'm getting error in the console saying that: 
**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined**

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    var one = $("#slider").offset();
    var two = $("#tabsDiv").offset();
    var three = $("#teaWare").offset();
    var four = $("#videoo").offset();
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var screenPosition = $(document).scrollTop();
        if (screenPosition < one.top) {
            $(".teavanamenu li a").removeClass("active");
            $(".teavanamenu li a.menu1").addClass("active");
        }
        if (screenPosition >= two.top) {
            $(".teavanamenu li a").removeClass("active");
            $(".teavanamenu li a.menu2").addClass("active");
        }
        if (screenPosition >= three.top) {
            $(".teavanamenu li a").removeClass("active");
            $(".teavanamenu li a.menu3").addClass("active");
        }
        if (screenPosition >= four.top) {
            $(".teavanamenu li a").removeClass("active");
            $(".teavanamenu li a.menu4").addClass("active");
        }
    });
    $(window).scroll();
    $(".one, .two").click(function () { $(window).scroll(); });
});
```

I'm not sure why it can't read the property top. Any help?

Comment: Are you setting the variable before or after the element is initialized? It has to be after or else the variable will be empty. Also, are you setting the variable to the correct id name?

Comment: Are you sure ` target_offset = *$('#' + trgt)*.offset(),` is finding anything?

Comment: $("#slider").offset() its getting undefined value, that's y you cant get the top value for the div

Comment: The error location I am getting on your site is not bring me to this snippet you provided.

Comment: @Matt sorry I pasted the wrong snippet

Comment: Thanks for the update. Okay, since it not registering my change in the browser of the code, could you add in `console.log($("#slider").offset());` and tell us the results?

Comment: in your html slider is commented use `$("#sliderDeskt")` in the place of $("#slider"), or remvoe comment.

Comment: Update: I just searched your source code and I did not find any **ACTIVE** elements with the ID of `slider`. I however did find one that is commented out? Was this intended?

Comment: Thanks guys. I realised that my ID was wrong. I replaced it with the correct name

Comment: wrong post, still got up vote :)